Docker Airflow - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright'
I have installed Docker and Docker Compose, and I'm setting up Airflow on my VM using Docker. I followed this guide: Running Airflow on Google Compute Engine (GCE) from Scratch.
Everything was successfully installed, but when I try to access the Airflow UI, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright'.
I'm attaching all the necessary details for your reference.
Dockerfile:
FROM apache/airflow:2.7.1

# Switch to root to perform installation tasks
USER root

# Update the package list and install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libnss3 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libxkbcommon-x11-0 \
    libdrm2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libxcb1 \
    xdg-utils \
    libasound2 \
    libdbus-glib-1-2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Python dependencies globally (not as user) to avoid permission issues
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

USER airflow
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

# Install Playwright globally and set up browsers
RUN pip install playwright
RUN playwright install

# Set environment variable to ensure Playwright is in the PATH
ENV PATH="/home/airflow/.local/bin:$PATH"

# Switch back to the airflow user
USER airflow

requirements.txt:
pandas
requests
argparse
futures
pyppeteer
aiofiles
playwright

Python version could see in container is 3.8.18
ramesh@airflow:\~/airflow-project$ docker exec -it bfbeac519df7 /bin/bash
airflow@bfbeac519df7:/opt/airflow$ airflow info

Paths info:
airflow_home    | /opt/airflow                                                                                                                                                                             system_path : "/root/bin:/home/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin     "                                                                      
python_path "/home/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/lib/python38.zip:/usr/local/lib/python3.8:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python
                | 3.8/site-packages:/opt/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/config:/opt/airflow/plugins"                                                                                                             
airflow_on_path | True     

I have tried the python path changing that also didnt worked out
docker-compose.yaml:
---
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.7.1}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/data:/opt/airflow/data
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 11s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO && gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPU available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs required. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10GB of disk space required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Not enough resources available to run Airflow.\e[0m"
          echo "Please check your resources and try again."
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        exec /entrypoint airflow db upgrade
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
    restart: "no"

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profile: debug
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: ["-c", "airflow"]

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
  redis-volume:

Error:
DAG Import Errors (1)expand_less
expand_moreBroken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/upload_to_google_drive_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/upload_to_google_drive_dag.py", line 7, in <module>
    from amazon_offers import main as amazon_offers_execute_crawling_script
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/amazon_offers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright'

ramesh@airflow:\~$ docker exec -it bfbeac519df7 /bin/bash

airflow@bfbeac519df7:/opt/airflow$ pip show playwright

WARNING: Package(s) not found: playwright

airflow@bfbeac519df7:/opt/airflow$

airflow info
ramesh@airflow:~$ docker exec -it bfbeac519df7 /bin/bash
airflow@bfbeac519df7:/opt/airflow$ airflow info

Apache Airflow
version                | 2.7.1                                                 
executor               | CeleryExecutor                                        
task_logging_handler   | airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler   
sql_alchemy_conn       | postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
dags_folder            | /opt/airflow/dags                                     
plugins_folder         | /opt/airflow/plugins                                  
base_log_folder        | /opt/airflow/logs                                     
remote_base_log_folder |                                                       
                                                                               

System info
OS              | Linux                                                                                                                                                                      
architecture    | x86_64                                                                                                                                                                     
uname           | uname_result(system='Linux', node='bfbeac519df7', release='5.15.0-1062-gcp', version='#70~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 24 20:12:18 UTC 2024', machine='x86_64', processor='')
locale          | ('en_US', 'UTF-8')                                                                                                                                                         
python_version  | 3.8.18 (default, Sep  7 2023, 13:47:34)  [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]                                                                                                             
python_location | /usr/local/bin/python                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                             

Tools info
git             | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
ssh             | OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022                                
kubectl         | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
gcloud          | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
cloud_sql_proxy | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
mysql           | mysql  Ver 8.0.34 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)                       
sqlite3         | 3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07 10e20c0b43500cfb9bbc0eaa061c57514f715d87238f4d835880cd846b9ealt1
psql            | psql (PostgreSQL) 15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg110+1)                                           

Paths info
airflow_home    | /opt/airflow                                                                                                                                                                             
system_path     | /root/bin:/home/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin                                                                           
python_path     | /home/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/lib/python38.zip:/usr/local/lib/python3.8:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python
                | 3.8/site-packages:/opt/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/config:/opt/airflow/plugins                                                                                                             
airflow_on_path | True                                                                                                                                                                                     

Providers info
apache-airflow-providers-amazon          | 8.6.0 
apache-airflow-providers-celery          | 3.3.3 
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes | 7.5.0 
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql      | 1.7.1 
apache-airflow-providers-daskexecutor    | 1.0.1 
apache-airflow-providers-docker          | 3.7.4 
apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch   | 5.0.1 
apache-airflow-providers-ftp             | 3.5.1 
apache-airflow-providers-google          | 10.7.0
apache-airflow-providers-grpc            | 3.2.2 
apache-airflow-providers-hashicorp       | 3.4.2 
apache-airflow-providers-http            | 4.5.1 
apache-airflow-providers-imap            | 3.3.1 
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure | 6.3.0 
apache-airflow-providers-mysql           | 5.3.0 
apache-airflow-providers-odbc            | 4.0.0 
apache-airflow-providers-openlineage     | 1.0.2 
apache-airflow-providers-postgres        | 5.6.0 
apache-airflow-providers-redis           | 3.3.1 
apache-airflow-providers-sendgrid        | 3.2.2 
apache-airflow-providers-sftp            | 4.6.0 
apache-airflow-providers-slack           | 8.0.0 
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake       | 5.0.0 
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite          | 3.4.3 
apache-airflow-providers-ssh             | 3.7.2 


